# Не удается подключить базу данных к BindingSource

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, ado.net

Хочу подключиться к базе данных через BindingSource Visual Studio 2022. При выборе источника через DataSource не находит тип Database.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]